# Filter duplicate events in reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

Let's say I have

```
x :: Event t (A,B)
```

I can get the first component of it:

```
fst <$> x :: Event t A
```

However, this event will fire even when the first component doesn't change. I want to avoid that, because it would trigger an expensive recomputation.

`A` is an instance of `Eq`, so I want to be able to remove the successive events where the first component is not changed compared to its last value.

Ideally, I'd like a function

```
filterDups :: Eq a => Event t a -> Event t a
```

which would do that without resorting to the `Moment` monad. Is it possible? Or what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember information about the history of the event to do what you want. As other answers have already mentioned, you can use `accumE` for that purpose. [Here](https://github.com/bernstein/breakout/blob/master/src/ReactiveUtils.hs#L54) a succinct definition:

```
unique :: Eq a => Event t a -> Event t a
unique = filterJust . accumE Nothing
       . fmap (\a acc -> if Just a == acc then Nothing else Just a)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never used reactive-banana, and haven't tested this, so beware. Nevertheless, here's one idea that at the very least typechecks. We'll use `accumE` to remember something about past events.

```
notice x (old, new) = (new, Just x)

changed (Just old, Just new) = guard (old /= new) >> return new
changed (_, new) = new

justChanges :: Eq a => Event t a -> Event t a
justChanges e = filterJust $ changed <$> accumE (Nothing, Nothing) (notice <$> e)
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses (or abuses) the fact that the `stepper` function updates the `Behavior` "slightly after" the `Event`, [see the comment in the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.7.1.3/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#v%3astepper).

First create a `Behavior` based on the `Event`, you have to find a suitable first value for the `Behavior` in your solution, for simplicity I am assuming that the first element of your pair is an `Int`:

```
x :: Event t (Int, b)

firstB :: Behavior t Int
firstB = stepper 0 $ fst <$> x
```

Then you can use the `filterApply` function:

```
filterDups e = filterApply (firstNotEq <$> firstB) e
    where firstNotEq old (new, _) = new /= old
          firstB                  = stepper 0 $ fst <$> e
```

Take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rtaboada/6944703) for a simple example using the [Threepenny GUI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui).

Comment: This implementation is correct in spirit, but there is a subtle problem when the event contains simultaneous event occurrences. The Behavior will only remember the last value of simultaneous occurrences, never the values in between. A completely correct implementation would use `accumE` here. However, future versions of reactive-banana will get rid of simultaneous occurrences in a single event altogether, so that the definition here becomes correct again.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this was my first time using reactive-banana and I wasn't sure if this solution was correct for all cases.